# Css transform altering text in ui-bootstrap uib-tabs

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following css:

```
.tabstyle {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background: #C8DEE9;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    content: '';
    -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
    transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif !important;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, when this renders, the tab looks as expected, but the text is skewed, I thought I could do something like:

```
.nav-tabs li a {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2;
    **transform: rotateX(-0.93deg)**
    font-style: normal !important;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But no go, how do I de-skew the resulting text?

Update:

[image]

Update #2:

```
 <uib-tabset active="activeTab" >
            <uib-tab index="$index + 1" classes="tabstyle" ng-repeat="tab in tabData" ng-if="!tab.disabled" select="changeTab(tab.route)">
                <uib-tab-heading>
                    <span class="material-icons {{tab.icon}}" style="vertical-align: middle"></span> {{tab.heading}}
                </uib-tab-heading>

                <!--<div ng-include="tab.content"></div>-->
            </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
```

Comment: define "skewed".. too narrow, too wide, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well.. the text looks italicized, using a browser to disable the transform + webkit transform lets the text render normally, but loses the shape of the tab.

Comment: that's because you're rotating X by .93deg. If you rotate it by say .2 it probably won't look italicised.   like this https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/7L4qh90y/

Comment: Maybe you can draw a picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of what they currently look like, that's supposed to be Times New Roman :)

Comment: @RandomUs1r Alternately/in tandem, you could increase the perspective. This could also help. This fiddle has the perspective set much higher, the rotate is at .4deg. https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/6rgqhw8e/ At .2 it doesn't look italicised at all to my eye, but i don't know if this is the effect you're after

Comment: @Rachel changing the rotateX on the tabstyle class changes the tab itself (however it does fix the text).  My question is how do I make the text look good while maintaining the angle in my tabs (I've uploaded a screenshot).

Comment: @RandomUs1r I updated this with blank icons https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ggmy10k3/

Comment: @RandomUs1r last go before i switch off for the night (it's 7 mins to midnight here) https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/Lp362a14/

Comment: @Rachel, I'm actually using ui-bootstrap for this, also I'm pretty dead set on having those slants in there.  I posted the code for the tabs.  Also, I'm following https://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/, I think it's #12 on there.  Somehow that example's text isn't skewed while mine is.   I'm thinking that this is either a z-index problem or I need to reverse the transform on the text only.